# Actuator don't expose endpoints in Spring Boot v2.4.3

Tags: spring-boot, endpoint, spring-boot-actuator

I want to expose all endpoints in my app. I included these dependencies that are necessary for actuator work:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And there is my application.properties file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= '*'
```

After starting the application (by Intellij or by the command `mvn spring-boot: run`), the logs contain the following line:

```
2021-06-25 15:07:39.253  INFO 21068 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

these endpoints are information and health. When I send this URL: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics` then I get 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quote the *

Instead use:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```